# Weighted Average Calculation With Negative Weight

Tags: math

I`m tring to calculate a weighted average but the formula a little bit different. 
The weight calculates in a different way:

When the value of the weight is higher the score is lower, for example:

I want to give a score to my customers, the

- Weight (Wi): The period time from the last purchases till today.
- Values (Xi): The value is the sale amount

So let's say I have 2 customers and one of them bought 2 months ago and the sale amount is 2000$. The other customer bought 12 months ago and the sale amount is 2000$. so the calculation is:

(2*2000 + 12*2000)/14

But in my case when the weight is higher it means that customer didn`t visit my business for a long time. But formula give to a customer with high number more score.

There is any way to manipulate the formula to calculate the weighted average for my needs ?

Thank you

Comment: Divide by weight instead of multiplying?

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply invert the time to get the weight (divide by rather than multiply by), as that would open up divide by zero errors, therefore the weight function has to be something like

w(0) = 1
w(very large) = 0

A simple candidate is w = 1 / (t + 1).

So in your example, that would be ($2000 / (2 + 1) + $2000 / (12 + 1)).

That, of course, is a weighted *total* - if you want the weighted *average*, sum all the weights and divide the total by that.

($2000 / 3 + $2000 / 13) / (1/3 + 1/13)

Comment: Shouldn't this include a normalization that is the sum of weights? In your example, you'd need to divide by (1/3 + 1/13).

Comment: @rwp - it wasn't clear to me from the OQ whether the poster wanted a weighted total (like in a sales pipeline) or a weighted average... If it's the latter, easy enough to divide the total by the sum of the weights...